# How to check for element.style in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check for a element style in Jquery, so if it has `style="width: 50%"` it should do something, what I have does not work so far, I do not want to check for CSS but the style element, any idea's?:

**`JS`**

```
  if($('#result-item').width() == '50%') {
     alert('50%');
  }
```

**`Html`**

```
<div id="result-item" class="search-result" style="width: 50%;">
</div>
```

Comment: A quick look at the documentation for [`.width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/): _"Get the **current computed width** for the first element in the set of matched elements"_ + _"The difference between `.css( "width" )` and `.width()` is that the latter returns a **unit-less pixel value** (for example, `400`) while the former returns a **value with units intact** (for example, `400px`). The `.width()` method is **recommended when** an element's width needs to be **used in a mathematical calculation**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier with vanilla JavaScript:

```
if($('#result-item')[0].style.width == '50%') {
    alert('50%');
}
```

You can also do it without any jQuery:

```
if(document.getElementById('result-item').style.width == '50%') {
    alert('50%');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try this, .width or .css('width') returns a value in px and not in %.

Can you simply add a *class* or a *data-* attribute to these divs ? In that way you could manipualte them easily.

```
const elts = document.getElementsByClassName = 'specific';
elts.forEach(elt => doSomething(elt));
```

Or,

```
$('.specific').each(elt => doSomething(elt));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var width = $('#result-item').width() / $('#result-item').parent().width() * 100
    if(width == '50') {
        alert('50%');
    }
```